# Translating matlab to c++

Tags: c++, matlab

i`m trying to translate some matlab code to c++ row by row without any bigger matlab knowledge. Everything went well till this one:

```
a = [1; A(:,n)];
```

I understand this is some matrix generation with its first row/first column element being 1, but Im not quite sure what the next part should do. Could you please give me a hint? "A" is a twodimensional double matrix, "n" is a for loop counter as I understand.

Regards

midin

Answer (score 1):

`A(:,n)` means: all Elements (`:`) from column `n`

So `a` = [1; all Elements for column `n` in `A`]

```
a = [1; A_n1; A_n2; A_n3 ...]
```